# SQL Trigger - determine if a field has changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have this trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tInsertTaskFromOpportunityReassignment] 
   ON [dbo].[OpportunityBase]
   FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

IF UPDATE(owninguser)
BEGIN
-- do the task
END
END
```

I only want to do the task if owninguser has actually changed. How can I determine that?

Thanks

Comment: You need to compare the values of the `owninguser` between the `deleted` table and the `inserted` table. However, not that triggers are fired per statement, not per row, meaning that if you update multiple rows, The trigger will only be fired once.

Comment: AFAIK it works even for multiple updated rows.

Comment: I was missing an `e`: should have been `note that triggers are...`. Anyway, it does work for multiple rows updated, but it's also possible that not all rows updated will have a different value in the specific column after the update.

Comment: Triggers should only ever be used for very simple tasks (writing a date timestamp to an audit field for instance). The process that fired the INSERT statement is best placed to know whether the value of owninguser has altered, and as such should be making the decision to fire an additional task; particularly if that task is complex/long-running.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tInsertTaskFromOpportunityReassignment] 
   ON [dbo].[OpportunityBase]
   FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE HasChanged int = 0;

SELECT @HasChanged = 1
FROM Inserted AS I
INNER JOIN Deleted AS D
ON I.PK = D.PK
AND IsNull(I.owninguser,'~') <> IsNull(D.owninguser,'~')

IF @HasChanged = 1
BEGIN
-- do the task
END
END
```

Compare the values of the field between Inserted and Deleted, joining the two tables on the primary key.

Comment: This will raise an error for update statements that include multiple rows where the `owninguser` column was changed.

Comment: @ZoharPeled makes a great point. The code for this answer assumes an  UPDATE statement will only ever affect a single row.

Comment: It will not throw an error for multiple row updates.  It will change the value of HasChanged to 1 if at least one row is updated.

Within the trigger, the IF statement can still make use of the Inserted/Deleted tables to affect further logic if HasChanged is true.

Comment: Yep, `@HasChanged` is assigned the proper value and is correct. However, the issue is that if "the task" must be performed on a per-owninguser basis, this answer is incomplete. We don't know--the OP hasn't clearly specified this IMO.

Comment: @DMason - It is not incomplete.  It will execute the task logic as long as a least one of the owning users has changed.  That is what was requested by the OP.  The OP did not ask for help with the task portion.  
My answer is not invalidated just because the OP might add more requirements.  None of us know what the task is, so every answer will be lacking that.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tInsertTaskFromOpportunityReassignment] 
   ON [dbo].[OpportunityBase]
   FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
/*
    I will assume that your [dbo].[OpportunityBase] table has a PRIMARY KEY
    or UNIQUE column that is immutable to join the inserted and deleted
    tables. In this example, [OpportunityBaseId] is that column.

    The SELECT query returns a set of all records that had the value of [owninguser] 
    changed. What you would do from that point is up to you.
*/
SELECT 
    i.[OpportunityBaseId], i.owninguser New_owninguser, d.owninguser Old_owninguser
FROM inserted i
JOIN deleted d
    ON i.[OpportunityBaseId] = d.[OpportunityBaseId]
    AND 
        (
            --owninguser value was changed.
            i.[owninguser] <> d.[owninguser] OR 

            --owninguser changed from non-NULL to NULL.
            (i.[owninguser] IS NULL AND d.[owninguser] IS NOT NULL) OR 

            --owninguser changed from NULL to non-NULL.
            (i.[owninguser] IS NOT NULL AND d.[owninguser] IS NULL)
        )
END 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use concat although it may potentially cause you problems with NULL and '':

```
CONCAT('', inserted.owninguser) <> CONCAT('', deleted.owninguser)
```